# What should I do about a reviewer who leaks final coordinates?

Tags: geocaching

Mystery- or multi-caches are not published with their real coordinates, but with fake coordinates that have to be within a certain distance of the cache. Reviewers however need to receive the real coordinates of the final cache (or all stations) to ensure that they are according to the guidelines.
Apparently some reviewers leak this information to fellow cachers, which is against the idea of mystery and multi caches.

I heard the story of a person who created mystery caches and send wrong final coordinates to the reviewer, people who solved the mystery were able to find the cache, but some people complained that the cache was nonexistent. After being questioned for the coordinates they were searching at, they posted the wrong coordinates that were given to the reviewer.
The person who left these reviewer-traps was reportedly met with hostility afterwards.

How should I correctly handle this problem if I ever encounter a reviewer who leaks coordinates?

Disclaimer: I am new to caching and have not encountered this problem myself, but heard about it in a podcast.

Comment: This is one of my questions on the [area51 geocaching proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60853/geocaching/62947#62947). I tried to ask questions I feel problematic to outdoors.SE there, but I guess it is better to put them to trial here.

Comment: I think I was hearing the same podcast ;-). Unfortunately I don't think this is a good question for a SX.com site as it quite closely relates to the rules and habits of a certain geocaching platform and would be much better discussed at their forum, FAQ or the like. I don't think it would be of use to discuss such stuff here as in the end the owner of the platform and/or the community there has to figure out how to deal with this issue.

Comment: @BenediktBauer I am more interested in the way I should handle the problem myself (eg: where or how should I report it), not how the problem could be solved. That would be a thing Groundspeak or the community has to handle of course.

Comment: Unless you can somehow wrap this social problem into the unique requirements of geocaching, this is basically about how to socially prevent spoilers from someone trusted with knowledge that was supposed to be kept secret. Like, what knot should be used to hang the cheater from a tree to shame them and discourage further spoilage of a game that people invested time to construct.

Comment: @bmike there are several implied questions: "is this behavior accepted by the community?" "is this behavior against any rule, or aren't there any?" likewise: "how does someone become a reviewer?" "are there ways I can report this to groundspeak?" (if it is against the rules)

Comment: Exactly - we have to guess a bit too much what you want us to answer. Perhaps winnow down to your first, core, currently unanswerable question and then ask a follow on question or two if needed to handle the entire situation?